# Rendering a custom 404 page without stopping the loader function in Remix React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, remix.run

In my app>routes>$.jsx file, the code looks like:

```
export async function loader() {
  throw new Response('Not found', {status: 404});
}

export default function Component() {
  return null;
}
```

And in my app>root.jsx file, I have the **CatchBoundary** function where I'll add my code for the 404 page, However, the issue is I need to render the 404 content inside my **Layout** component, which requires **loader** and **useLoaderData()** to get the **headerContent** and **footerContent**. But whenever an error is thrown, Remix short-circuits the loader and triggers error handling, so I can't access the data that I need inside the **CatchBoundary** function. Here's my relevant snippet code for the app>root.jsx file:

```
export async function loader({context}) {
  const layout = await context.storefront.query(LAYOUT_QUERY);
  const [headerNavLinks, footerMenus, footerBottomLinks, newsletterCopy] =
    await Promise.all([
      getHeaderContent(),
      getFooterMenus(),
      getFooterBottomLinks(),
      getNewsLetterCopy(),
    ]);

  const layoutContent = {
    headerContent: {
      headerNavLinks,
    },
    footerContent: {
      footerMenus,
      footerBottomLinks,
      newsletterCopy,
    },
  };

  // TODO: Reflect on better name for layoutContent
  return defer({
    layout,
    layoutContent,
  });
}

export default function App() {
  const {layout, layoutContent} = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
          <Layout layout={layout} content={layoutContent}>
            <Outlet />
          </Layout>
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export function CatchBoundary() {
  const {layoutContent} = useLoaderData();
  const caught = useCatch();
  if (caught.status === 404) {
    return (
      <Layout content={layoutContent}>
        <p>Custom Error Page</p>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
  // render a generic 500 error page
}
```

My Layout component looks like this:

```
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';

export default function Layout({children, content}) {
  const {headerContent, footerContent} = content;

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
      <div>
        <a href="#mainContent" className="sr-only">
          Skip to content
        </a>
      </div>
      <Header headerContent={headerContent} />
      <main role="main" id="mainContent" className="flex-grow bg-primary7">
        {children}
      </main>
      <Footer content={footerContent} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm getting the error that userLoaderData() is undefined and it makes sense since the loader stops working right when the error is thrown, I've tried so many things but can't seem to make it work. any pointers will be very helpful.